# How to make a piecewise activation function with Python in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, activation-function

The active function in my CNN has the form:

```
abs(X)< tou  f = 1.716tanh(0.667x)
x >= tou     f = 1.716[tanh(2tou/3)+tanh'(2tou/3)(x-tou)]
x <= -tou    f = 1.716[tanh(-2tou/3)+tanh'(-2tou/3)(x+tou)]
```

`tou` is a constant.

So, in TensorFlow it is possible to make your own activation function. I don't want to write it in C++ and recompile the whole of TensorFlow.

How can I use the function available in TensorFlow to achieve it?

Comment: The three conditions seem inconsistent. For instance what happens when x==tou?

Comment: the 3rd condition is wrong. I have edited it again. please have a try. thanks~

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow it is easy to write your own activation function if it's include already existed ops, for your case you can use `tf.case`

```
f = tf.case({tf.less(tf.abs(x), tou): lambda: 7.716 * tf.tanh(0.667 * x),
         tf.greater_equal(x, tou): lambda: 1.716 * tf.tanh(2 * tou / 3) + 1.716 * tf.tanh(2 * tou / 3) * (x - tou)},
        default=lambda: 1.716 * tf.tanh(-2 * tou / 3) + 1.716 * tf.tanh(-2 * tou / 3) * (x + tou), exclusive=True)
```

Comment: the third condition is wrong. I have edited it again. please have a look. thanks~