# Why does a custom activation function cause network both zero loss and low accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn, activation-function, custom-build

I was trying to build a custom activation function using tflearn by making following changes:

add my custom activation function to `activation.py`

```
def my_activation(x):
    return tf.where(x >= 0.0, tf.div( x**2 , x + tf.constant(0.6)) , 0.01*x)
```

and add it to the `__init__.py`

```
from .activations import linear, tanh, sigmoid, softmax, softplus, softsign,\
relu, relu6, leaky_relu, prelu, elu, crelu, selu, my_activation
```

**Since tensorflow can perform the gradient calculation automatically, I don't need to implement the gradiate function**. As pointed in the article [Deep Learning Programming Style](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/architecture/program_model.html),

> In the past, whenever someone defined a new model, they had to work out the derivative calculations by hand. While the math is reasonably straightforward, for complex models, it can be time-consuming and tedious work. All modern deep learning libraries make the practitioner/researcher’s job much easier, by automatically solving the problem of gradient calculation.

I trained the model on cifar10 dataset using this code: https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_cifar10.py
but changed all **relu** activations to **my_activation**.

Sadly, this simple modification cause the network fail to learn anything:

```
Training Step: 46  | total loss: 0.00002 | time: 1.434s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00002 - acc: 0.0885 -- iter: 04416/50000
Training Step: 47  | total loss: 0.00002 | time: 1.448s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00002 - acc: 0.0945 -- iter: 04512/50000
Training Step: 48  | total loss: 0.00001 | time: 1.462s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00001 - acc: 0.0927 -- iter: 04608/50000
Training Step: 49  | total loss: 0.00001 | time: 1.476s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00001 - acc: 0.0896 -- iter: 04704/50000
Training Step: 50  | total loss: 0.00001 | time: 1.491s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00001 - acc: 0.0919 -- iter: 04800/50000
Training Step: 51  | total loss: 0.00001 | time: 1.504s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00001 - acc: 0.0890 -- iter: 04896/50000
Training Step: 52  | total loss: 0.00001 | time: 1.518s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00001 - acc: 0.0944 -- iter: 04992/50000
Training Step: 53  | total loss: 0.00001 | time: 1.539s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00001 - acc: 0.0989 -- iter: 05088/50000
Training Step: 54  | total loss: 0.00001 | time: 1.553s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00001 - acc: 0.0951 -- iter: 05184/50000
Training Step: 55  | total loss: 0.00000 | time: 1.567s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 0.0964 -- iter: 05280/50000
Training Step: 56  | total loss: 0.00000 | time: 1.580s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 0.0931 -- iter: 05376/50000
Training Step: 57  | total loss: 0.00000 | time: 1.594s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 0.0903 -- iter: 05472/50000
Training Step: 58  | total loss: 0.00000 | time: 1.613s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 0.0851 -- iter: 05568/50000
Training Step: 59  | total loss: 0.00000 | time: 1.641s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 0.0835 -- iter: 05664/50000
Training Step: 60  | total loss: 0.00000 | time: 1.674s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.00000 - acc: 0.0834 -- iter: 05760/50000
```

Since I am just a beginner, I don't know **the reason causing the network became both zero loss and low accuracy** (NaN output? Deadweight?). Can anybody tell me how to fix this? thanks!

**Please Note that I'm not asking how to build a custom activation function.** Questions about how to make a custom function:

- [How to make a custom activation function with only Python in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow)
- [How to make a piecewise activation function with Python in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769719/how-to-make-a-piecewise-activation-function-with-python-in-tensorflow)
- [How do you create a custom activation function with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915482/how-do-you-create-a-custom-activation-function-with-keras)
- [How do I use custom activation functions in TensorFlow for Neural Networks?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-custom-activation-functions-in-TensorFlow-for-Neural-Networks)
- [Is it possible to add new activation functions to TensorFlow / Theano / Torch? How?](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-add-new-activation-functions-to-TensorFlow-Theano-Torch-How)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a custom activation function with only Python in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does a custom activation function cause network both zero loss and low accuracy?

Because this network doesn't backpropagate through your new activation. What you did is just a beginning in creating a custom activation function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39921607/712995): "... As explained in the sources mentioned above, there is a hack to define gradients of a function using `tf.RegisterGradient` and `tf.Graph.gradient_override_map`...".

I'm actually not sure that your activation is much better than [`tflearn.activations.leaky_relu`](http://tflearn.org/activations/#leakyrelu), but if you really want to provide a custom activation, you'll have to code the gradient and register it like described above.